# OR condition in the Haskell List comprehensions

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I am learning `haskell`. I want to know how to have `OR` condition in the `haskell list comprehensions`

Basically I want numbers which are `divisible by 3 or 5`

I tried this

```
[ x | x <- [0..1000], x `mod` 3 == 0 , x `mod` 5 == 0]
```

But this is only giving `divisible by 5`

Comment: The `OR` operator is `||`

Comment: `(||) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool` and is described as "Boolean 'or'". https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Bool+-%3E+Bool+-%3E+Bool

Answer (score 4):

The way you have written your comprehension means that, you have two predicates and the result will include all the elements which satisfy all the predicates. So, your program finds all the numbers which are divisible by 3 and 3. Instead

just use OR operator, like this

```
[ x | x <- [0..1000], x `mod` 3 == 0 || x `mod` 5 == 0]
```

to get all the numbers which are either divisible by 3 or 5. And notice that we have only one predicate in this comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it's giving you all the numbers that are both divisible by 5 and 3. The reason behind this is that `,` in there is equivalent to `&&` so:

```
[x | x <- range, a, .., c]
```

is equivalent to:

```
[x | x <- range, a && ... && c]
```

You can however have any kind of condition within each comma separated section; including but not limited to:

```
-- Logic OR
or :: [Bool] -> Bool
|| :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool

-- Logic AND
and :: [Bool] -> Bool
&& :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
```

for example, in your case you can use:

```
divisibleBy :: Integral a => a -> a -> Bool
divisibleBy x y = (x `mod` y) == 0
```

and then:

```
[x | x <- [0..1000], x `divisibleBy` 3 || x `divisibleBy` 5]
```

Alternatively you can simply use:

```
[x | x <- [0..100], any ((== 0) . (x `mod`)) [3, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Comma (,) is AND.**

And single pipe `|` is such that.

```
Prelude> [x | x <- [0..100], x `mod` 3 == 0, x `mod` 5 == 0]
[0,15,30,45,60,75,90]
```

So this says give me all x such that x is in range [0..100] AND divisible by 3 AND divisible by 5. This gives you numbers divisible by both 3 and 5.

Do this to get what you want

```
Prelude> [x | x <- [0..100], x `mod` 3 == 0 ||  x `mod` 5 == 0]
```